# White space no longer dynamic after adjusting range of axis in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

When item in the legend is toggled off, the active datapoints will take up the freed space in the plot. However, if the y-axis range has been adjusted, the space remains empty.
How to fix?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'red': np.random.randn(50),
    'blue': np.random.randn(50) + 2,
    'green': np.random.randn(50) + 1, 
    'orange':np.random.randn(50) + 3, 
})

fig = go.Figure()
for i in df.columns:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            x=df[i], 
            y=[i] * df[i].shape[0],
            name=i,
            mode='markers',
            marker_color= 'blue' if 'blue' in i else 'green' if 'green' in i else 'red' if 'red' in i else 'orange',
            legendgroup=i,
            showlegend=True
        ))
fig.update_layout(legend_traceorder='reversed')
fig.show() # if one item in the legend is toggled off, all space will be redistributed to displayed data points

# after adjusting range, space will remain empty when toggled off some data
fig.update_layout(height=800) # to maximize the impact the issue 
fig.update_yaxes(range=[-0.5, len(df.columns)-0.5])
fig.show()
```

[image]